# How to pass data array in a POST request in Postman?

Tags: api, post, postman

I have created POST api 
I need to pass this below data in postman how to pass this data

```
{
  "orderData": {
    "customer_id": 2,
    "products": [
      {
        "product_id": 1,
        "qty": 1
      },
     {
        "product_id": 13,
        "qty": 1
      }
    ],
    "shipping_method": "flatrate_flatrate",
    "payment_method": "checkmo"
  }
}
```

I tried to pass below but shows error
[image]

Can anyone please help me into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Add the data to be Posted in the **Body** tab as **raw** data as highlighted.